# HMAC_Init_ex Corrupting Stack Space

Tags: c, macos, openssl

I'm trying to create a SHA256 hash with a key using OpenSSL's HMAC functions. My stack keeps getting corrupted (every value set to 0) after I call HMAC_Init_ex. I'm using Xcode and running OS X 10.8.5. Running "openssl version" in my terminal outputs "OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013".

Here is my function and all my `#include`s:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

char* hash(char *str, char* key){
    int inputLen = strlen(str);
    int keyLen = strlen(key);
    HMAC_CTX ctx;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, keyLen, EVP_sha256(), NULL); // Everything is fine up to here.
    HMAC_Update(&ctx, str, inputLen); // By the time this line runs, str and key are NULL, and inputLen and keyLen are 0.
    char* ret = malloc(65*sizeof(char));
    HMAC_Final(&ctx, ret, 65);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    ret[65] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

This code should be working. It probably has something to do with my libraries, but I don't know what. Did I do something wrong when importing the libraries?

**Update:**
I found an example from [here](http://www.askyb.com/cpp/openssl-hmac-hasing-example-in-cpp/) that uses the fully encapsulated `hmac` function and says that this is essentially the same as what I was doing before, and strangely, it works. So I have circumvented my problem, but you could still answer in case it helps somebody else. Except it's probably some weird, specific issue with my libraries. The working function:

```
char* hash(char *str, char* key){
    int inputLen = strlen(str);
    int keyLen = strlen(key);
    unsigned int retLen = 65;
    char* ret = emalloc(retLen*sizeof(char));
    ret = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, keyLen, (unsigned char*)str, inputLen, NULL, NULL);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What is your compile command? Also, check the return values of `HMAC_CTX_init` and `HMAC_Init_ex`.

Comment: @ooga They're both void. Sorry, I forgot to say that I'm using Xcode to build this. I don't know how to check the compile command, if there is one.

Comment: I checked `ctx` after `HMAC_CTX_init`, and nothing appeared strange, but I don't know exactly what it should look like.

Comment: That is odd. I just built and ran [**this sample**](http://pastebin.com/kVG4xGPy) in Xcode 5.1.1. Fwiw your "null-termination" thing at the end of your code is completely wrong (its message digest; it doesn't produce an asci string; you have to *make* one from the bytes as the linked sample shows) but I can't see how that would be related to your issue.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried a different library function, and it worked… Yeah, I realize now that I need to convert it to a string myself. Facebook didn't like my hashed token very much!

Answer (score 1):

You missed [OpenSSL/Initialization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSL/Initialization).The ENGINE or ssh config provides you with the cipher methods, digest methods, etc.

```
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

    HMAC_CTX ctx;

    result = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * result_len);

    ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();
    ENGINE_register_all_complete();

    HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
    HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, 16, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&ctx, data, 8);
    HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &result_len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction about the engine, but after adding those two lines, I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

use [ssh -Version] get openssl version,when the version less than 1.0.1e, should use HMAC_Init... instead of HMAC_Init_ex...

in version 1.0.1e, the implement of HMAC like this

```
unsigned char *HMAC(const EVP_MD *evp_md, const void *key, int key_len,const unsigned char *d, size_t n, unsigned char *md,unsigned int *md_len)
{
    HMAC_CTX c;
    static unsigned char m[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];

    if (md == NULL) md=m;
    HMAC_CTX_init(&c);
    if (!HMAC_Init(&c,key,key_len,evp_md))
        goto err;
    if (!HMAC_Update(&c,d,n))
        goto err;
    if (!HMAC_Final(&c,md,md_len))
        goto err;
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&c);
    return md;
    err:
    return NULL;
    }
```

you can compare the HMAC() API in the later version of openssl